# how can a bot add a reaction to a question i answer on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**discord.py Bot**

I want that my Discord bot add a reaction to the question, on my Server, I already answer.

I search already for a resulution but I cant find one.

Example:

[image]

Thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reaction like this:

```
@bot.command
async def react(ctx):
    await ctx.add_reaction("✅")
```